# Why am i getting this ... is not a function Error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am exporting an object.
Here is my file named "token.js"

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const secret = "mysecret"

module.exports = {
   generate : function(id){
      return jwt.sign({id:id},secret);
   },

   verify : function(token, callback){
      jwt.verify(token, secret,callback);
   },

   authenticateUser: function(req,res,next){
      var token = req.method =="GET" ? req.query.token : req.body.token;
      if(!token) return this.authenticationFailure (req,res);

      this.verify(token, function(err,user){
          if(err) return this.authenticationFailure (req,res);

          req.body.user = user;
          next();
      });
   },

   authenticationFailure : function(req,res){
      res.json({response:"Failed to authenticate"});
   }
}
```

Then from my app i request this file, the generate method and verify method works fine is called from the api directly. The problem comes when i call authenticateUser, the method is called but it when the method called "this.authenticationFailure" or "this.verify" it returns an error that they are not functions. They appear as functions to me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the code where you call the functions?

Comment: Your callback for `this.verify` on `authenticateUser` has a different context for `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `authenticateUser` method is probably used like this:

```
something(yourModule.authenticateUser);
```

Where `something` does this:

```
funcation something(callback) {
    ...
    callback(req, res, next);
}
```

Here you see, that `callback` is called on its own, not as a method of the object, so the original `this` is lost.

General soulution is to catch `this` to some variable to be able to get it later.
Here you can use the module object itself:

```
var myModule = {};
module.exports = myModule;

myModule.authenticateUser = function(req,res,next){
  var token = req.method =="GET" ? req.query.token : req.body.token;
  if(!token) return myModule.authenticationFailure (req,res);

  myModule.verify(token, function(err,user){
      if(err) return myModule.authenticationFailure (req,res);

      req.body.user = user;
      next();
  });
};

myModule.authenticationFailure = function(req,res){
  res.json({response:"Failed to authenticate"});
};
```

Inside the `authenticateUser` you use `myModule` variable instead of `this`.

Answer (score 2):

Add `var self = this;` in your functions and use `self` wherever you would have used `this`.

This will ensure your "this" context is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

When the callback provided to `this.verify` is executed, its contextual `this` will be different from your `module.exports` object. Every function in JavaScript has a contextual `this`, but `this` defaults to the global object when not otherwise bound. In your callback function, no contextual `this` is bound.

You need to maintain that context. There are a few ways to achieve this.

ES5?

The `self = this` style:

```
authenticateUser: function(req,res,next){
      var self, token = req.method =="GET" ? req.query.token : req.body.token;
      if(!token) return this.authenticationFailure (req,res);

      self = this;
      this.verify(token, function(err,user){
          if(err) return self.authenticationFailure (req,res);
      });
   },
```

or [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
authenticateUser: function(req,res,next){
      var token = req.method =="GET" ? req.query.token : req.body.token;
      if(!token) return this.authenticationFailure (req,res);

      this.verify(token, (function(err,user){
          if(err) return this.authenticationFailure (req,res);
      }).bind(this));
   },
```

The ES6 solution is to use [fat arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which maintain the contextual `this` of their parent scope.

```
authenticateUser: function(req,res,next){
      var token = req.method =="GET" ? req.query.token : req.body.token;
      if(!token) return this.authenticationFailure (req,res);

      this.verify(token, (err,user) => {
          if(err) return this.authenticationFailure (req,res);
      });
   },
```

Take a look at the MDN articles on [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/call), and [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/apply) for a better understand of how contexts work.